# How Tensorflow use cudnn

Tags: tensorflow

I'm reading Tensorflow source code currently, and curious about the implementation of kernels. I found that most of the gpu implementation pointing to Eigen. Could anyone can tell me how tensorflow use cuDNN via Eigen, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most basic kernels use Eigen which uses plain CUDA. Kernels that use cuDNN (e.g. convolution) go through this integration: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda

Here is an example Conv kernel that [retrieves](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/603b713669b5637c098d18eef6cccc45cb356924/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc#L853) supported Conv algorithms (including cuDNN if it is linked and available), run and [chooses the best one](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/603b713669b5637c098d18eef6cccc45cb356924/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc#L890), and finally, [uses](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/603b713669b5637c098d18eef6cccc45cb356924/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc#L897) it.